# Use tf-lite C++ API for both Android and iOS

Tags: android, c++, ios, c, tensorflow-lite

I am a mobile developer, using C++ to build portable parts of my apps that work on both Android and iOS.

Here is my workflow:

- For portable parts, I code a cross-platform library on macOS, build/unit-test it on macOS
- then, build/unit-test it on Linux
- create android and ios builds of the library using the respective toolchains, and integrate it into the mobile apps

While exploring tflite, I can see multiple APIs: C, C++, Obj-C, Swift, Java.

To write portable code, Obj-C/Swift/Java APIs are out of picture.

Is there any common API (C or C++) which can be used to evaluate tf-lite models on macOS, Linux, Android and iOS? If yes, what are the bazel targets to build?

Answer (score 2):

Google has recently released [Mediapipe](https://github.com/google/mediapipe) which is cross platform & its calculators are written in C & C++. But this framework is useful in Video analytics with tflite. 
If you want to use tflite for other purpose you can modify [mediapipe](https://github.com/google/mediapipe) implementation at calculators levels which are written in native (C & C++) only.